# What is the scope of business logic which should be placed in a stateless session bean?

Tags: separation-of-concerns

I'm struggling to wrap my head around sizing business logic placed in stateless session beans. It is important that I have little experience in this topic.

In the case I have now, there is a JEE application where a REST service (JAX-RS) is responsible for providing data to external systems. In the application the business logic consists of the following:

- getting data from database via Stateless Session Beans
- getting data from other sources, usually from other services via a REST client
- merging data structures to the desired form
- mapping the structure to DTO classes being fit for a contract

According to my plan, there will be an application which is responsible for controlling the business logic steps, it has @EJB, REST client and Mapper injected.

In my mind, @EJB is responsible only for communicating with the database, as a repository. I have the feeling Session beans are designed more as representatives of business logic, including all logic I described above.

If I let session beans be more fat, then the application library is not needed, so my whole application is lighter, less complex. The only question is testability, which has to be investigated.

So, my question is: what is the healthy size of a session bean? Can all of the business logic be placed in session beans? Is there a guideline worth to follow?